Upgraded to 24.04.01 - now system randomly shuts down
Specs:

Ubuntu 24.04.01
AMD Ryzen
NVIDIA GeForce RTX
Kernel: 6.8.0-47

Problem:
After upgrading to 24.04.01 I've had all sorts of problems. Most of them I've managed to fix or work around except for:

Cannot suspend or even blank the screen (probably because of the NVIDIA card)
Joining a voice channel in Discord means my bluetooth headphones stop working
Laptop randomly reboots

It's the third one that's driving me nuts. I can find no pattern to when it reboots and the log files (i.e. journalctl -b -1 -e) show no consistency in messages. Even if I have nothing running it sometimes reboots in 10 mins. Sometimes I'll have lots of apps running and it'll stay up overnight. Sometimes it's the opposite. The only thing I've noticed is as long as I'm using the laptop it doesn't reboot - rebooting seems to happen when I'm not actively typing/mousing.
I've dug through the forums and tried just about everything (AppArmor, Discord, downgraded drivers - Nvidia is at 470 now, played with grub parameters, etc...) but nothing makes any difference.
This is hugely frustrating since I can't step away from the laptop without it rebooting on me and losing everything I was working on.
I have no idea what the problem is, how to diagnose it, or what to try next.
EDIT #1
I just discovered that 24.04 borked my dual boot. Great. Now I'm finding problems faster than I can fix them.
